# JavaScript: how do I wait for a function to end before proceeding to next line?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I'm using JavaScript to do some smooth animations for pop-up content. When a button on my site is clicked, an iframe appears in the foreground with some content loaded from an html file.

I'm having a problem with my fade-out animation. I call two functions, opacityfadeout() and resetzindex(), in that order. However, the z-index of the iframe changes before the fade-out occurs.

I need resetzindex() to run *only* after opacityfadeout() has fully completed (bringing the opacity of the iframe to 0).

What is the simplest and cleanest solution to this simple dilemma?

```js
function closecontent()
{
    opacityfadeout();
    resetzindex();
}

function opacityfadeout()
{
    var f = setInterval(function()
    {
        if(opacityvalue > 0.0)
        {
            opacityvalue -= increment;
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(f);
        }
        iframe.style.opacity = opacity;

    }, 16);
}

function resetzindex()
{
    iframe.style.zIndex = "-5";
}
```

Comment: One solution is to pass `resetzindex` function as an argument of `opacityfadeout` and use it as a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) when the latest one is done.

Comment: Or maybe you can do it with promises.

Comment: @AbdouBestmood promises may have dependencies based on the browser context.  "Simplest" in this case must be callbacks.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function closecontent()
{
    opacityfadeout(resetzindex);
}

function opacityfadeout(callback)
{
    var f = setInterval(function()
    {
        if(opacityvalue > 0.0)
        {
            opacityvalue -= increment;
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(f);
            if (callback) callback()
        }
        iframe.style.opacity = opacity;

    }, 16);
}

function resetzindex()
{
    iframe.style.zIndex = "-5";
}
```

Comment: well put. :) (I think we did exactly the same thing).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer thank you, also I think we posted these at almost the exact same time

Comment: After seeing this I actually thought of an easier way. I just call resetzindex() inside the else { } block. Which is working fine.

What I don't understand, though: why don't I have the same effect if I just call resetzindex() at the end of opacityfadeout()? Like after the line "}, 16);"

Comment: @vrealwavy the reason it doesn't work in your sample code above is because you're not considering the asynchronous code from the `setInterval`. Your `closecontent` will run synchronously, but the interval will continue to run over and over until the interval is cleared. The code in `closecontent` does not wait for the interval to finish before executing resetzindex. My solution just waits until the interval is cleared and also executes the callback at the same time

Comment: @vrealwavy as far as just calling resetzindex where I execute the passed in callback, you can do that, but that only works because you have resetzindex in the scope there, and it also couples these functions so they need to be together, if this is the only time you'll be using `resetzindex`, just replace the whole line with `iframe.style.zIndex = "-5"`. Passing in a callback is a common javascript pattern which allows you to execute any function you want upon completion of an asynchronous task.

Answer (score 1):

Have `resetzindex` be sent as a callback parameter to `opacityfadeout` and call that once your interval is finished.

```
function closecontent() {
  opacityfadeout(resetzindex);
}

function opacityfadeout(after) {
  var f = setInterval(function() {
    if(opacityvalue > 0.0) {
      opacityvalue -= increment;
    } else {
      clearInterval(f);
      !!after && after();  // if you like compiler love letters...
    }
    iframe.style.opacity = opacity;
  }, 16);
}

function resetzindex() {
  iframe.style.zIndex = "-5";
}
```